# Android Studio gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

Is it possible to have methods and actual coding inside each item for a GridView?

The app that I am attempting to create is a currency converter, and I am currently displaying 3 images in the gridView: Euros, Pesos, and Rupees.

Once the user clicks on one, I want the open to open up a new XML which displays a textView. The user enters the value of US dollars in the textView and clicks the compute button. The app then displays the converted amount in the bottom of the screen.

The problem is that I am unable to figure out how to open up a new XML every time a picture is clicked on in the gridView. Assuming that I am able to do this, I am also unsure of where to place the code that goes behind the conversions. Would I make a new `.java` or just place is all in `MainActivity.java`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be best doing is when the user clicks on a currency it takes them to another activity where you would then load another xml for whatever you want to show.

In order to detect which item had been clicked you can implement an onItemClickListener for example

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

         //this assumes you give the gridview a list of currency which it then displays. Here we get the currency selected to then pass to our new activity 
         String selectedCurrency = myArrayOfCurrencies.get(position);

          //then start new activity and give it the currency. This means we won't have to create an activity for each currency. You just need to create 1 and then based on what currency you give it will change the functionality 
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, Converter.class);
         Intent.putExtra("currency", selectedCurrency);
         startActivity(intent); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should be able to detect the clicks on each item of the `GridView` by calling the `setOnItemClickListener()` method. 
If you set the `clicklistener` and you still can't detect the clicks, then most probably you need to add those attribtutes to your  imageView in the xml

```
android:focusable="false"

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Second, once you are able to detect the clicks you can start new activity or add fragment that contains that edit text that will promote the user to enter the value.

Third, I would suggest to put the code responsible for the currency conversion in a class separately and create static methods that takes a value and convert it to the other curreny such as:

```
public class CurrencyConverter {

public static double convertToRupees (String currencyType, double currencyValue){
         ....
                  return currencyInRupees;
           } 
}
```

and by the way I would suggest you to use RecyclerView with grid layout manager instead of GridView.

Answer (score 0):

I would create more classes.
You asked how to open a different XML file for each gridView item.

1. Create a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter.
2. Override getView and for each view attach the right Xml file, according to the position.

For example:

YourActivity.java:

```
GridView gridView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());
}
```

MyAdapter.java:

```
...
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return XmlArr.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return XmlArr[position];
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Xml myXml = (Xml) getItem(position);
    Holder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {  
        // Set your view's layout. Consider using LayoutInflater.
        // Use a static holder to prevent re-initialization:

        holder = new Holder();
        // holder.textView = ...
        // holder.Xml = ...
        // Or whatever you decided to have in each gridView item.

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.Xml = myXml;
    ...

    return convertView;
}

static class Holder() {
    TextView tv;
    Xml xml;
    ...
}
```

I assumed you would used an Xml array (xmlArr).
Now you have option to play with each gridView item as you wish. You can set each view/button/textView an onItemClickListener, or you can also set the whole gridView an onItemClickListener (from YourActivity.java).

Hope this helps.